# `object' is undefined due to async function that fetched data in useEffect hook in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-hooks

I am fetching an `object` from `api` using `axios.get("url")`. The object fetched successfully (in `Animal` state) but there is a component level `state (imageState)` which requires updation using `setState` with fetched data.   
Code:
Component:

```
import React,{useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
const AnimalDetail = ({match}) => {
    const [Animal ,setAnimal ] = useState({})
    const Id = parseInt(match.params.id)
    const [imageState, setImageState] = useState ("");
 
useEffect(()=>{
            const fetchAnimal = async () => {
                const {data} = await axios.get(`/api/animals/${Id}`)
                setAnimal(data)
            }
            fetchAnimal()
            // setImageState(Animal.image[0])   // need to access first index of image object
    },[])

    useEffect(()=>{

   setImageState(Object.values(Animal.image)[0])  // error cant convert undefined to object
}
   
    return (
        <>
       <h2>imageState </h2>  //undefined
        <h2>{typeof(Animal.image)}</h2>  //gives object
       </>
  )
}
export default AnimalDetail
```

Backend Api :

```
{"id":2,
"image":["/image.jpg","/image2.jpg"],
"price":60000,
"breed":"",
"isAvailable":true,
"weight":110,
}
```

How can i fetch the data and update the component level state periodically(after fetching)?

Comment: Can you `console.log(data)` and edit your post to tell me what you get?

Comment: It looks like you declare imageState a second time after your useEffect. This is not the main problem, but you will need to delete that line eventually.

Comment: Is there a compelling reason not to do `setImageState(data.image[0])` inside fetchAnimal?

Comment: @samuei yes there is no problem is doing that too. The real problem still here with me is the `typeof(Animal.image)` that gives **object** but when i just `console.log(Animal.image)` then i get **Array ["img1",''img2"]**. I actually need to `map` these images into divs.

Comment: `typeof` returns "object" for arrays, so that's expected.

Comment: @MichaelHoobler I assigned {data} to component state(Animal) and when i `console.log(Animal)` i get an `object` in console like this `Object { id: 1, image: (1) […], breed: "", isAvailable: true, weight: 100,  … }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try following, maybe this can help you. Removed the second `useEffect` and updated the image state in the first `useEffect`.

And also I can see, you have declared `const [imageState, setImageState] = useState ("");` twice.  You can remove the second one.

Also, make sure you handle the API error in `useEffect` otherwise this may break the application on API failure.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
const AnimalDetail = ({ match }) => {
  const [Animal, setAnimal] = useState({});
  const Id = parseInt(match.params.id);
  const [imageState, setImageState] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchAnimal = async () => {
      const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/animals/${Id}`);
      setAnimal(data);
      setImageState(data.image[0]);
    };
    if (Id) {
      fetchAnimal();
    }
  }, [Id]);

  return (
    <>
      <h2>imageState </h2> //undefined
      <h2>{typeof Animal.image}</h2> //gives object
    </>
  );
};
export default AnimalDetail;
```

Answer (score 2):

your code has some error in the second useEffect.
you can use this one :

```
     useEffect(() => {
if (Animal) setImageState(Object.values(Animal.image)[0]); // error cant convert undefined to object
      }, [Animal]);
```

this is because the Animal should have value first.
and you are defining imageState two times in your code! the first one is enough.